# Where html filesystem save files ? How to get them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Where does html5 filesystem store the files and folders, and can i use them in my hard drive, or somehow. For example can i use these files in my filesystem from other pc ?

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ ?

Comment: yes, not the tut but the API , so yes this API i mean

Comment: I think that depends on the browser and afaik you don't have any possibility to access the filesystem from the outside. This is meant to be a sandbox for security reasons.

Comment: I would imagine that the answer varies between the different browsers and operating systems.

Comment: What browser should be used and how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When testing using Chrome Canary on my Mac it stores the contents of the file here:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome\ Canary/Default/File\ System/002/t/00/00000000
```

The `002` part seems to update per "app" and I'm guessing the `00/0000000` part is the "directory/file". Then the meta data, like directory name and file name and other information is stored in this directory:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome\ Canary/Default/File\ System/002/t/Paths
```